# Linux Kernel Hot(un)pluggable memory granularity with Dax

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm currently working on DAX device driver for my device and stumbled upon a problem.
The device has it's own ram, which can be mmapped to any app with no problem.
What i want to do is to be able to give OS the memory my device doesn't use at the moment.
So if device has nothing to do, the memory can be utilized by OS.
I've researched the topic and found out that there's actually a possibility to do so:
https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/mm/memory-hotplug.html

The article mentioned above says that memory can be hotplugged on memory block granularity.
But how exactly one does so?

There's an utility called daxctl, which can actually map memory regions to OS from DAX device and back:

https://docs.pmem.io/ndctl-user-guide/daxctl-man-pages/daxctl-reconfigure-device

It actually works, but it disables device completely. This functionality was added in the patch:
https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20190124231448.E102D18E@viggo.jf.intel.com/

So to map DAX device to OS, user required to use sysfs.
To make this work, management software must remove the device from
being controlled by the "Device DAX" infrastructure:

```
echo -n dax0.0 > /sys/bus/dax/drivers/device_dax/remove_id
echo -n dax0.0 > /sys/bus/dax/drivers/device_dax/unbind
```

and then bind it to this new driver:

```
echo -n dax0.0 > /sys/bus/dax/drivers/kmem/new_id
echo -n dax0.0 > /sys/bus/dax/drivers/kmem/bind
```

But with this approach it removes all memory from device.

Is there any possibility, maybe in recent kernels, to map only part of DAX device memory (several memory blocks, for example)?
If my device has 32Gib can i give to the os only 8Gib (or any arbitrary amount of memory on the memory block granularity)?
Maybe there's the other way to do so?

Ideally would be that my device managed it's memory blocks and on memory rank level and could hotplug 4Gib from rank0 and 8Gib from rank1, for example.

If small scale kernel modification is required it's ok.
Maybe that kmem driver can be modified to only map some of memory blocks from the device to OS.
I just don't have much expertise on the topic.
Highly appreciate any advice!

Comment: Why not asking Dave directly?

Comment: @0andriy I've tried to reach him by e-mail. But he doesn't respond

Comment: You should probably answer to that email thread. You can download it in an _mbox_ format by running `b4 mbox https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20190124231448.E102D18E@viggo.jf.intel.com/` (note, `b4` is in the repositories of all popular Linux distributions).